# In Javascript, queuing the execution of function if the function is already executing, but cancel any previously queued

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've faced the following scenario quite often so I'm wondering if there is a built-in jQuery way of solving the issue.

Imagine the following code:

```
$(document).click(function() {
   paintCanvas();
});
```

The problem with this code is that if the user clicks on the screen 50 times in rapid succession you are going to overload the browser with 50 calls to paintCanvas.

If paintCanvas is currently executing and a new request is created, we want to queue the new request so that it waits until paintCanvas is finished executing. However, at the same time, we can drop any previously queued calls to paintCanvas as we only care about the final state of the mouse, not all the intermediate states.

Here is some code that solves the problem:

```
var _isExecuting, _isQueued;

function paintCanvas() {
    if (_isExecuting) {
        if (!_isQueued) {
            _isQueued = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                _isQueued = false;
                paintCanvas();
            }, 150);
        }
        return;
    }

    _isExecuting = true;

    // ... code goes here

    _isExecuting = false;
};
```

[This AJAX queue plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/) essentially implements this functionality, but does so only in terms of AJAX. Surely this is a very common problem that can be solved in more generic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want throttle/debounce features.

There are no built in methods that I know of from jQuery, you can use any of these though:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

http://jsperf.com/jquery-throttle-methods

Comment: Ext-JS has the same concept built in when setting a handler, you can give it options like Element.addListener("click", this, {buffer: 150}), which would always wait 200 milliseconds before calling your handler (unless it was called again, at which point it would restart the counter).http://docs.sencha.com/core/source/Observable.html#method-Ext.util.Observable-addListener I know the user asked about jQuery, I just wanted to mention that other frameworks have this built-in

Comment: I, for one, can't stand jQuery :) I much prefer OO code instead of  procedural code. That is why I use Ext-JS which is completely OO based.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to solve this problem with `mousemove` because the system already does that for you.  While `paintCanvas` is executing, it is not generating hundreds of mousemove events even if the mouse is moving vigorously.  Rather, the next event will be the current location of the mouse, not a queue of all the intervening mouse events.

Look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4ZuMn/.

Wiggle your mouse around in the body (lower, right pane) as fast as you want.   Then move the mouse out of the pane and notice that the count stops immediately - there are no more mouse events.  It doesn't stack up mouse events ever.  Whenever the system is ready for the next mouse event, it gets the latest position of the mouse.  Individual mouse moves are NOT queued up - they do not accumulate.  You can also see in the listing of mouse events that lots of intervening mouse events are not present (e.g. lots of coordinates are missing) even though the mouse went through more positions.  This is because the system wasn't ready to make a mouse event when the mouse was in that position so that position was skipped.

Further, because javascript is single threaded, you will never get a new mouse event while you are currently processing one.  The system won't generate a new one until you're done processing the one you're already one.  So, you will never, ever see `_isExecuting` as `true` in javascript in your code.  You simply don't need that check.  And, since you don't need that check and it will never be true, none of your queuing code will ever execute.  You can see here in this jsFiddle, that you can never catch a mousemove event that was re-entered: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ngnUT/.  The inAction flag is never caught as true, no matter how fast or much you wiggle your mouse around.

Comment: Fair enough, but I wasn't concerned with mousemove, that was just an example to illustrate, but rather any situation where you have to worry about potentially running multiple methods in parallel. Take clicks instead - what happens if the user clicks on 50 different things. You don't want to execute the method 50 times, you only want to execute it for the last click. I've updated the example to reflect. I suspect my particular solution won't work anyway because of the reasons you describe. But the problem remains.

Comment: I disagree, while it's true that the browser does buffer mousemove events, you may want to buffer them for an even longer time than what the browser does. But your comment on why `_isExecuting` is not needed is dead on.

Answer (score 1):

Though @rkw provided a link, I always prefer to show code here on SO. Here's some simple code that kind does what you want. A function that returns a buffered version of another function. This will keep delaying until it stops receiving the event for the given `delay`. You can tweak this if you don't want to to wait for the delay after the last event. All you'd need to do is keep track of when you first set the timeout and offset the subsequent calls to `setTimeout`.

Here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/qfFjZ/

```
function createBuffered(handler, delay) {
  var timeoutId = null;

  return function() {
     var me = this;
     if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
     }
     timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
         handle.apply(me, arguments);
         timeoutId = null;
     }, delay);
  }
}
```